# Setting the Min and Max values of a XamDataGrid Field

Tags: wpf, xaml, field, infragistics, xamdatagrid

So I have a `XamDataGrid` with a percent field.

```
<igWPF:XamDataGrid  DataSource="{Binding Data}" DataValueChanged="XamDataGrid_DataValueChanged">
   <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
      <igWPF:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False" AllowAddNew="False" AddNewRecordLocation="OnBottomFixed" />
   </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
   <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
      <igWPF:FieldLayout>
         <igWPF:Field Name="Percent" />
      </igWPF:FieldLayout>
   </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
</igWPF:XamDataGrid>
```

I need to set the percent field to have 100 as a maximum value. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a numeric field, i.e. `int` / `Int32` and set the field editor type to `XamNumericEditor`. Then, you can define a `ValueConstraint` that specifies the minimum and maximum values.

```
<igWPF:XamDataGrid  DataSource="{Binding Data}" DataValueChanged="XamDataGrid_DataValueChanged">
   <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
      <igWPF:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False" AllowAddNew="False" AddNewRecordLocation="OnBottomFixed" />
   </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
   <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
      <igWPF:FieldLayout>
         <igWPF:Field Name="Percent" DataType="{x:Type sys:Int32}" BindingType="Unbound">
            <igWPF:Field.Settings>
               <igWPF:FieldSettings EditorType="{x:Type igEditors:XamNumericEditor}">
                  <igWPF:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                     <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamNumericEditor}">
                        <Setter Property="ValueConstraint">
                           <Setter.Value>
                              <igEditors:ValueConstraint MinInclusive="0" MaxInclusive="100" />
                           </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                     </Style>
                  </igWPF:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
               </igWPF:FieldSettings>
            </igWPF:Field.Settings>
         </igWPF:Field>
      </igWPF:FieldLayout>
   </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
</igWPF:XamDataGrid>
```

For more information, see the code example for [Configuring XamNumericEditor](https://www.infragistics.co.kr/help/wpf/xamdatagrid-fields-editors-configuration-#_Ref372811963) and others:

- [Default Editor Types for Different Data Types](https://www.infragistics.co.kr/help/wpf/xamdatapresenter-define-a-field-layout)
- [About xamDataPresenter and xamEditors](https://www.infragistics.co.kr/help/wpf/xamdata-about-xamdatapresenter-and-xameditors)

Comment: when I added the following "sys:Int32" it gave the following error: namespace sys doesn't exist

Comment: @NourMawla If your are using Visual Studio, it should be able to automatically import missing namespaces, but you can also do that manually, by adding this namespace in XAML `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"`.

Comment: now it gave the error Int32 doesn'y exist in namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime

Comment: @NourMawla Sorry, that was the namespace for .NET Core. If you use .NET Framework, paste this namespace `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`.

Comment: it worked...thank you so much....but I noticed that my project isn't automatically adding namespaces. do you know why?

Comment: @NourMawla I am glad it worked. I do not know why the namespaces were not added automatically, maybe you do not have IntelliSense or a setting is wrong. Normally, if you paste XAML or other code in the editor, it will mark missing types red and ask you to choose importing a suitable namespace.